# Deploy Symfony2 app in shared hosting without run any command

Tags: php, symfony, caching, deployment

I'm trying to deploy a Symfony2 application in a shared hosting and everyone knows that nobody can run any command on that type of hosting so this is what I do in order to get things done and after reads the [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/deployment/tools.html) at Symfony.com site:

All this was done in my development server:

- Run the command `php composer.phar install --no-dev --optimize-autoloader`
- Run the command `php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug`

Then after all was done I copied the entire folder to my shared hosting but now I'm getting this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with
>   message 'The stream or file
>   "/var/www/html/tanane/app/../var/logs/prod.log" could not be opened:
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory' in
>   /home/tanane72/public_html/tanane/var/cache/prod/classes.php:5014
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /home/tanane72/public_html/tanane/var/cache/prod/classes.php(4958):
>   Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler->write(Array) #1
>   /home/tanane72/public_html/tanane/var/cache/prod/classes.php(4883):
>   Monolog\Handler\AbstractProcessingHandler->handle(Array) #2
>   /home/tanane72/public_html/tanane/var/cache/prod/classes.php(5083):
>   Monolog\Handler\AbstractHandler->handleBatch(Array) #3
>   /home/tanane72/public_html/tanane/var/cache/prod/classes.php(5388):
>   Monolog\Handler\FingersCrossedHandler->handle(Array) #4
>   /home/tanane72/public_html/tanane/var/cache/prod/classes.php(5488):
>   Monolog\Logger->addRecord(500, 'Uncaught PHP Ex...', Array) #5
>   /home/tanane72/public_html/tanane/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/EventListener/ExceptionListene
>   in /home/tanane72/public_html/tanane/var/cache/prod/classes.php on
>   line 5014

The file `prod.log` exists in shared hosting but Symfony is looking in my development server as this line said `/var/www/html/tanane/app/../var/logs/prod.log`, where I can change that behavior? How the process works in order to change this route to the current one on shared hosting?

Comment: That's because you upload the cache directory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to copy all files to shared hosting, except `app/cache` and `app/logs` dirs. And then in `app/config/parameters.yml` change database connection to new one.
Then set permissions on `app/cache` and `app/logs` dirs to `777`

That's all

P.S. And don't forget to check PHP version on hosting, better use `5.4` or `5.5`.